# What is the behavior of Coldfusion cftransaction tag when multiple databases are accessed?

Tags: database, coldfusion, transactions

The coldfusion documentation, (I'm using CF8) states:

> Changes to data that is requested 
>   by the queries are not committed to the datasource until all actions within 
>   the transaction block have executed successfully.

But it also states:

> In a transaction block, you can write queries to more than one database, but you must commit or roll back a transaction to one database before writing a query to another

I have multiple transactions in my code base which access 2 databases for both selects and update/inserts. The code assumes that all queries will either succeed or they will all be rolled back. But I don't know if that is true based upon the line in the docs that says: "but you must commit or roll back a transaction to one database before writing a query to another".

What is the behavior if a write to the first database succeeds, then the subsequent write to another database fails? Will the first be rolled back?

Comment: I would be surprised if CF8 even allows it... Have not used it in a long while, but most later versions prevents this even from happening by throwing an error when queries within the same transaction have different DSN's.

Comment: What is your interpretation of `but you must commit or roll back a transaction to one database before writing a query to another`?

Comment: .. specifically are you referring to datasources or databases? Also what is your DBMS?

Comment: @Leigh, I am using SQL server 2005, and I am referring to databases, not datasources.

Comment: @DanBracuk I don't think that statement bears an interpretation, it is unambiguous, but i inherited this code and the original authors did not commit or roll back transactions between writes to separate databases. The code works. But I am trying to determine what is supposed to happen in the case of an exception during a write to the second database. Will the first databases write be rolled back? Or will it be committed?

Comment: @ReubenRomandy - If it is the same *datasource*, but different databases, the exact behavior is controlled by the DBMS itself.  The `cftransaction` simply triggers CF to send a `begin / commit / rollback transaction` sql command off to your database. How those commands are handled is up to the DBMS: [SQL Server BEGIN TRANSACTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the documentation means is that you must put a `<cftransaction action="commit">` after the queries to one database before you can move on to using another datasource. It will throw an error if it detects that you have `<cfquery>` tags with different datasources inside of a transaction without using the commit. See your database documentation for exact transaction support as the CFML via the database driver is only sending in transaction commands on your behalf, it is not responsible for their execution or behavior. Enable JDBC logging in your database to see this in action.

Won't work:

```
  <cftransaction action="begin">

    <cfquery datasource="foo">
    select * from foo_test
    </cfquery>

    <cfquery datasource="bar">
    select * from bar_test
    </cfquery>

  </cftransaction>
```

Will work

```
<cftransaction action="begin">

    <cfquery datasource="foo">
    select * from foo_test
    </cfquery>

  <cftransaction action="commit"><!-- Commit before switching DSNs --->

   <cfquery datasource="bar">
    select * from bar_test
    </cfquery>

</cftransaction>
```

If you are using three part names for multiple database access through a single datasource, the transaction control will work.

```
<cftransaction action="begin">

    <cfquery datasource="foo">
    INSERT INTO foo_test ( id )
    VALUES ( 70 )
    </cfquery>

    <!-- insert into the bar database via the foo datasource --->
    <cfquery datasource="foo">
    INSERT INTO bar.dbo.bar_test (id )
    VALUES ( 'frank' ) <!-- Fails because not an int and the prior insert into foo is rolled back -->
    </cfquery>

</cftransaction>
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up J.T. We are using three part names for multiple databases through a single datasource. The documentation did not make this distinction clear to me. I appreciate your detailed answer.

Comment: @J.T.  -  While the third scenario *usually* works, it is probably more accurate to say the exact behavior, and any exceptions, are dbms specific. Since all CF does is issue transaction commands to the database. The handling is up to the DBMS. FWIW, I found the descriptions in the documentation a bit ... wacky ;-) They should just say a `cftransaction` cannot span multiple datasources - period.  You must use two separate transaction tags, because that essentially what committing midstream does anyway...

Comment: @leigh Sure, it's not like CF or the JDBC driver is actually doing any transaction management.

Comment: @J.T. - Yep, I just meant to someone unfamiliar with cftransaction, it may not be crystal clear that the expected behavior is not necessarily the same across the board. There may be exceptions. So ultimately the answer is "check the documentation for {your DBMS here}".

Comment: @ReubenRomandy Don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score -2):

The default behaviour for CFTransaction is that all writes will be rolled back if there is an exception anywhere within the transaction block. So if one query fails, all queries are rolled back.

This is only if the database supports commits and rollbacks based on Transaction Control Language, a subset of SQL.

However you can granulary control how CF transaction works, beyond the default behaviour, including features such as savepoints and nested transactions.